# Lazy loading not fading in with javascript & css

Tags: javascript, css

I have added some code that loads the image once it is 25% visible in the viewport. I have added a CSS animation to fade in onload. The fade happens if the image is in the viewport, but not while loading, how can I add this fade to this image when the images are loaded with javascript or CSS?

```js
let options = {
  root: null,
  rootMargin: '0px',
  threshold: 0.25 // Visible by 25%
};

let callback = (entries, observer) => {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    if (entry.isIntersecting &&
      entry.target.className === 'lazyImage') {
      let imageUrl = entry.target.getAttribute('data-img');
      if (imageUrl) {
        entry.target.src = imageUrl;
        observer.unobserve(entry.target);
      }
    }
  });
}

let observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options)
observer.observe(document.querySelector('#lazyImageId'))
```

```css
.lazyImage {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  object-fit: cover;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-name: fadeIn;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 full-height">
  <img id="lazyImageId" class="lazyImage" data-img="./img/dog.jpeg" alt="" loading="lazy">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I'd approach this is adding a class to the `img` once it's visible (either `.complete` or `onload`:

```js
if (imageUrl) {
   entry.target.src = imageUrl;
   observer.unobserve(entry.target);

   if (entry.target.complete) {
        entry.target.classList.add("visible");
      } else {
        entry.target.onload = function() {
        entry.target.classList.add("visible");
      }
    }
 }
```

[**Above edited with onload function mentioned by @Amir**]

Make sure your `img` has `opacity: 0;` before it receives the animation. So in the CSS, I'd use:

```css
.full-height {
  /* height for demonstration effect */
  height: 2000px;
}

.lazyImage {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  /* top position for effect*/
  top: 1000px;
  left: 0px;
  object-fit: cover;
  opacity: 0;
}

.lazyImage.visible {
  animation: fadeIn 1s ease forwards;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

Once the `img` receives the "visible" class, it can now animate.

Since your `img` tag is already in the DOM before the `src` is loaded, it has already animated before it is visible.

```css
.full-height {
  /* height for demonstration effect */
  height: 2000x;
}

.lazyImage {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  /* top position for effect*/
  top: 1000px;
  left: 0px;
  object-fit: cover;
  opacity: 0;
}

.lazyImage.visible {
  animation: fadeIn .5s ease forwards;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 full-height">
  <h1>Scroll Down</h1>
  <img id="lazyImageId" class="lazyImage" data-img="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1620125587503-54b5365229de?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2550&q=80" alt="" loading="lazy">
</div>
<script>
  let options = {
    root: null,
    rootMargin: '0px',
    threshold: 0.25 // Visible by 25%
  };
  let callback = (entries, observer) => {
    entries.forEach(entry => {
      if (entry.isIntersecting &&
        entry.target.className === 'lazyImage') {
        let imageUrl = entry.target.getAttribute('data-img');
        if (imageUrl) {
          entry.target.src = imageUrl;
          observer.unobserve(entry.target);
          if (entry.target.complete) {
            entry.target.classList.add("visible");
          } else {
            entry.target.onload = function() {
              entry.target.classList.add("visible");
            }
          }
        }
      }
    });
  }
  let observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options)
  observer.observe(document.querySelector('#lazyImageId'))
</script>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/AliKlein/pen/RwpbxjQ)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding the question, you are looking to fire the fade in animation only after the image has fully loaded.

There are two things I use when checking if an image has fully loaded.

1. The [HTMLImageElement complete attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/complete) which is a read only attribute that lets you know if the image has completely loaded. If you were to only use this, you would have to continually check this attribute until it was true then run your animation, which isn't great.
2. The [onload EventHandler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) which runs after the image has fully loaded. So if we have a slow loading image we can wait for it to finish loading before we run our animation.

Using those in tandem will mean you're covered for both cases of whether the image is loaded or still loading while your code is running.

I altered your callback just a little to include the use of `.complete` and the `.onload` event handler

```js
let callback = (entries, observer) => {
    entries.forEach(entry => {
        if(entry.isIntersecting && entry.target.className === 'lazyImage') {
              // Might as well store the img element in a variable since we need it for so much
              let imgEle = entry.target;
              let imageUrl = imgEle.getAttribute('data-img');
            
              if(imageUrl) {
                  imgEle.src = imageUrl;
                
                  // Check if the image has already loaded, if so add our animation class to it
                  if (imgEle.complete) {
                      imgEle.classList.add('animate');
                  } else {
                      // If it hasn't finished loaded an a load even listener that will add the class once it's done
                      imgEle.onload = () => {
                          imgEle.classList.add('animate');
                      };
                  }
  
                  observer.unobserve(entry.target);
              }
          }
      });
}
```

Finally, for the actual animation itself, I just created a `.animate` class that has the actual animation CSS within it and then I'm adding the `.animate` class to the image elements once they're loaded.

```css
.animate {
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-name: fadeIn;
}
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/abehmaram/hv3oc4Lf/1/) with all of the above in it as well to test it out.

Hopefully that answers the question you were asking, if not let me know and I can remove/edit as needed.